# How to transfer data from one ViewController to another through closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have 2 viewController. I make the transition from one viewController to another, then perform actions, and when I return, I have to pass data to the first viewController, but a prerequisite is to do this through the closure

for example
code in ViewController 2

```
 var string: ((String) -> Void)?
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    strii?("Lol")
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all give the closure a better name

```
var callback : ((String) -> Void)?
```

In the `IBAction` call it

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {
    callback?("Lol")
    dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

In the first controller for example in `prepare(for segue` assign the closure

```
let destinationController = segue.destination as! MyGreatController
destinationController.callback = { string in
   print(string)
}
```

Comment: Not related to this answer but I want to say that your answers are very helpful and concise.. thank you